# UrlFetchApp.fetch in spreadsheet OnSubmit errors with "Don't t have permissions" despite manifest

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-forms

**How can I fetch an external URL every time my form gets submitted?**

---

I need to archive an URL submitted with Google Forms.

I created an app script for Google Spreadsheet associated with my form:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  var url="https://web.archive.org/save/http://www.google.com"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
}
```

I also edited manifest to include the permission allowing to use the `UrlFetchApp.fetch`:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/(redacted)",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"]
}
```

However I keep getting the following error message:

> You do not have permission to call UrlFetchApp.fetch.
>   Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request

Comment: Reauthorize/recreate the trigger... Declaring the required permissions is not the same as *agreeing to them*

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested your code and works perfect for me. Maybe the error has to do with the `headers` you are using.

Also remember that the `onSubmit` is not a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), meaning that you have to install it in before. Simple trigger suffer from various [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions), one being:

> They cannot access services that require authorization.

So in your case you need to use [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). First create and execute a code that creates the trigger, after that a consent screen will pop up, for you to accept the scopes of the trigger function.

An example for an [`onFormSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/form-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) could be something like this:

```
function createTrigger(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<your-sheet-id>");
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onSubmit')
           .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
           .onFormSubmit()
           .create();
}
```

In this case the `onSubmit` is the name of the function to be called when the trigger is executed (your function).

Execute this `createTrigger` and accept the permissions.

Now everything should work normally, and be executed every time with the right permissions.